# Magento not showing Custom Template Page content

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have created 4 CMS Page templates to use for non-product content. I have uploaded the template files to: 
`app/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/template/page/` dir. The files I have uploaded are copies of the existing 1column.phtml file, but when I choose that page template from the Design->Layout pulldown menu and try to preview the page I get a blank page, no error, nothing. If I select the 1column page option the content shows properly.

**Here is my config file**

code/local/FL/CorporateTemplates/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>

                <corporate_template_lithograph>
                    <label>Corporate Template - Lithograph</label>
                    <template>page/corp-lithograph.phtml</template>
                </corporate_template_lithograph>

                <corporate_template_wideformat>
                    <label>Corporate Template - Wide Format</label>
                    <template>page/corp-wideformat.phtml</template>
                </corporate_template_wideformat>

                <corporate_template_packaging>
                    <label>Corporate Template - Packaging</label>
                    <template>page/corp-packaging.phtml</template>
                </corporate_template_packaging>

                <corporate_template_photography>
                    <label>Corporate Template - Photography</label>
                    <template>page/corp-photograph.phtml</template>
                </corporate_template_photography>

            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Here is my etc/module file**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <FL_CorporateTemplates>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </FL_CorporateTemplates>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: have you checked the exceptions log and PHP errors? So it seems like you are getting the new templates in the dropdown but not rendering. Can you post the content of one of the phtml files?

Comment: Have you flushed cache?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `layout_handle` for each:

```
<global>
    <!-- snip -->
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <corporate_template_lithograph>
                <label>Corporate Template - Lithograph</label>
                <template>page/corp-lithograph.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>corporate_template_lithograph</layout_handle> <!-- arbitrary value -->
            </corporate_template_lithograph>
        <layouts>
    <page>
<global>
```

That allows you to define the layout update which will be used in conjunction with this page layout setting in your module's layout XML file. See [***app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml***](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml#L145) for examples.